# How to adjust stackview with child view and add constarint

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uistackview

[image]I am leaning iOS programming in objective-c. In Xcode, I am trying to add stack view that encompass a table view. However, the storyboard showed some warning or error that indicates I should set constraints to the stack view and the table view as well in the Y-axis as well as adding constraint.
I spent some time to find out how to set that right, but at the end the stack view because distorted and appears as shown below in the image.

Please advice and let me know how to adjust the constraint of stack view and its included table view.

**imageView**

```
      [![attempt to add constarint to stack view][1]][1]


       [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJdyn.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not understanding your question very clearly but one thing i think you are missing is the understanding of how a stackview works .

Stack views are given a defined size at the begining and depending on the views inside the stack view it has the ability to change its height and width. Thats the whole point of using a stack view . So if you are having a stack view inside a . table view what you should do is givena constraint to the stackview depending on which way you are adding the elements .

If you are adding the elements in a verticle manner , you have to set the stack view positioning constraints from `leading` and `trailing`. The reason is if the elements within is added verticle there is no reason for the horizontal alignment to change hence you give a constraint horizontally .

However if you add the elements horizontally , you give a constraint to the top and bottom of the stack since then there is no reason for that to change .

and the stack will change its size (width or height) depending on the element sizes within.

[image]